# Use Magic Device with Robe of Stars

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, rogue

I'm playing a Rogue, archetype Thief, approaching level 13 which is when I'll gain the ability "Use Magic Device".
My character inherited a Robe of Stars as a family heirloom.
Can I use this? I am not currently attuned to other items.
I haven't found any info online that approves or forbids it exactly, but no mention of this specific circumstance either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### You can use it now (after a short rest). No need for Use Magic Device.

The only requirement for using the [Robe of Stars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/robe-of-stars) is that you attune to it, and there are no specific attunement restrictions for it. The [rules for attunement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement) state:

> Attuning to an item requires a creature to spend a short rest focused on only that item while being in physical contact with it (this can't be the same short rest used to learn the item's properties). This focus can take the form of weapon practice (for a weapon), meditation (for a wondrous item), or some other appropriate activity. If the short rest is interrupted, the attunement attempt fails. Otherwise, at the end of the short rest, the creature gains an intuitive understanding of how to activate any magical properties of the item, including any necessary command words.

So just take a quick nap with your new robe and attune to it, and you're ready to surf the Astral Plane.

Answer (score 6):

Use Magic Device (PHB p. 97) allows the Rogue Thief to ignore class restrictions when using a magic item.

A Robe of Stars (DMG p.194) does not have any class restrictions. Compare Robe of Stars to Robe of the Archmagi below it.